# Add page indicator with viewAnimator

Tags: android, indicator, viewanimator

I have been trying to add a page indicator to a viewAnimator.

Have tested this option for a viewFlipper and it dosent work so good because they are two different things.

https://asishinwp.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/android-viewflipper-with-page-indicator/

Anyone have some good ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [this](https://github.com/avianey/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) interesting library

> Android ViewPagerIndicator
>   Paging indicator widgets that are compatible with the ViewPager from the Android Support Library to improve discoverability of content.